# Print the value of the series x = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + … + 1/n for the user’s input of n

Tags: python

Python 2 how to do this.Print the value of the series x = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + … + 1/n for the user’s input of n.

Comment: Read a https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ - topics: input() and for-loops. Calculate it ,print it. Not really a question for SO -we do not teach basic language usage. Please read about what we do here: [tour] [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
n = int( input() ) # reading user input
x = 0 
for i in range(1, n + 1): # adding 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n
    x += 1.0/i

print(x) # => outputs : 2.283333333333333
```

Comment: For Python 2, this gives you a result of 1, due to how `1/i` is dealt with.

Comment: @BillM. fixed ! ^^

Comment: Read a sentence (as a string) in all lowercase from the user. Use a for loop to capitalize the first
letter in each word of the sentence.

Comment: what about this one? txs

Comment: @KaiShengCheng user_input.title()

Answer (score 0):

There may be a Harmonic Series function in Python packages like `math` or `numpy`, or some similar way to deal with it, especially if you need high precision at large values of n.  Otherwise, you could just do this:

```
>>> n = 5
>>> print(sum(1.0/i for i in range(1,n+1)))
2.28333333333
```

Note that the "1.0" is important for Python 2.x so that it knows to deal with floats.  Otherwise things get rounded along the way:

```
>>> print(sum(1/i for i in range(1,n+1)))
1
```